# New graphics card causing internet lag spikes, but only while gaming?

Tags: graphics-card

Well I recently had an Nvidia GeForce GT 430 graphics card installed on my computer.Ever since then, I've had random lag spikes while gaming. Browsing the internet is fine, and my speed test and ping test remain the same. However, when playing games such as Wolf Team or COD: Black Ops, I'll periodically get 3-10 second lag spikes every 30 seconds or so in which I am usually killed. It's extremely frustrating. How can I fix this?

Note: all my drivers are up to date.

Comment: this may be better off migrated to Superuser

Comment: @Xantec - it's likely to get closed on Super User as it mentions games. They're quite strict about adhering to the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: Can you verify these problems only occur on online games? Do you have any demanding single player games (e.g Crysis) to check that it is your Internet connection that is suffering lag?

Comment: What was your previous GPU? I'm guessing your current GPU (being an entry level card) has troubles rendering your games.

Answer (score 1):

The 'lag' you see isn't necessarily your network card. It could be the bottleneck between your Graphics card and your CPU.  What resolution do you run at? If you lower it, do you perform better? If you increase it (say to something like 1600x1200) does it do better?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you may have an overheating problem, can you run an utility to either:

- underclock your card or reduce your settings
- monitor the GPU temperature

The symptoms of overheating can include what you described.